# Endomorphism ring of a quiver representation over an algebraically closed field.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, quiver

I'm in trouble with an exercise. The text asks to consider a quiver with only one loop, a field $k = \mathbb{F}_2(t)$, and a representation $V$ given by the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  t \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
It asks to calculate the endomorphism ring, $End_k(V)$ and $End_\bar{k}(V)$, where $\bar{k}$ is the algebraic closure of k.

For the ring $End_k(V)$ I applied the definition of morphism and I found that the ring is the set of matrices: \begin{bmatrix} a &  ct \\ c & a \end{bmatrix}
with $a$ and $c$ in $k$.

What should I do now for the case with $\bar{k}$?

Comment: If we want to calculate $\bar{k}$ morphisms  of  $V$, we should have one $\bar{k}$-vector space.  How does $V$ look like a $\bar{k}$-linear space ?